# Device not fetch locations inside Closed Area

Tags: android, service, gps

My Application requires to update locations to the Server Continuously so that it gets notifications of any nearby places.

I have written a background Service to run location services and update locations to server.  Everything works fine but the thing is when I am inside a Closed Area(example I am inside my home), It is unable to fetch location and location services running continuously which is draining device battery.

When I test it under sky, it works perfect. I will remove updates for sometime when I got a location update and start fetching again.

if anyone has come across this kind of issue, help me in this regard.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: its because there is limited connectivity of internet at ur home ... u should use good connector

Comment: @KailashDabhi I haven't expected such answer. I have very good Internet Connectivity. I would accept your answer if the same hadn't worked with iPhone. the same works very much fine with iPhone but not with my Android device

Answer (score 1):

From my experience it depends on your location provider / source

- Mobile network ~500-1000m accuracy
- WIFI ~25m accuracy
- GPS up to 10m accuracy

You need to be connected to your mobile network to get a location from it, WIFI network the same, and GPS generally wont work unless you are outside / can see the sky!